# How to change Inno Setup DisplayName uninstall entry

Tags: inno-setup

I'm creating an installer using Inno Setup, it is creating a registry key under

```
HKLM\SOSTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\My_Key
```

I want to overwrite `DisplayName : My Program version 1.0` to `DisplayName : My Program 1.0`.

I have added following line in the script but it is not working.

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\My_Key"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: "DisplayName"; ValueData: "My Program 1.0"; \
    Flags: createvalueifdoesntexist
```

I.e. It is creating `DisplayName : My Program version 1.0` instead of `DisplayName : My Program 1.0`.

Is there anything I should do in the script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format of the `DisplayName` entry is governed by the [`UninstallDisplayName` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstalldisplayname). It defaults to the value of the [`AppVerName` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appvername), which in turn defaults to `NameAndVersion` "custom" message

```
NameAndVersion=%1 version %2
```

with `%1` replaced by a value of the [`AppName`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appname) and `%2` replaced by a value of the [`AppVersion`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appversion).

So either:

- Change the `UninstallDisplayName` (or the `AppVerName`) to the explicit value you want:

  ```
  [Setup]
  UninstallDisplayName=My Program 1.0
  ```
- Or change the `NameAndVersion` message to exclude the "version" part:

  ```
  [Messages]
  NameAndVersion=%1 %2
  ```